# Return GameObject to start position after OnMouseUp C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a Drag-n-drop game and wondering how I can save an gameobjects position, and then return an object to that position when OnMouseUp starts. This is supposed to be added to multiple objects.

Currently Im using this for the mouse-events, and that is working pretty good.

```
void OnMouseDown()
        {
        screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
        offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
        Debug.Log("Clicked "+gameObject.name);
        }
public void OnMouseDrag()
        {
        Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
        Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint)+offset;
        }
void OnMouseUp()
        {
        Debug.Log("Returning gameobject to startposition"); 
        }
```

What shall I do to return the object to start position when OnMouseUp.
Been looking online for ways to do it, but I cant find a sulution

Comment: you need to store away a copy of the object's position when you start the drag (on mousedown I guess) and then on mouse up set the object's position to the stored position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Unity but I took a guess (so type names and stuff might need correcting...also answer might be wrong):

```
Vector3 _originalPosition;
void OnMouseDown()
{
    _originalPosition = gameObject.transform.position;
    screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
    ...
}

void OnMouseUp()
{
    gameObject.transform.position = _originalPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you make an empty GameObject to the Hierarchy, place it in the exact position of your player, store it as a variable to make it move as the player moves? Through this, you can use its transform.position as the record of moves the player has made.